# I want to delete everything I've contributed to Stack Exchange sites

Tags: discussion, support, user-accounts, deleted-answers, moderators

I'm angry, and I can't properly express myself in English as I would like to defend myself, so this is going to be a short message:

Due to a bad decision of a moderator who suspended my account in superuser and  also I THINK THAT (I'm not sure) he deleted what a friend has published in his account, I have decided to delete all the answers that I've published during my years in StackOverflow, and not only the answers, also the questions, in both StackOverflow and SuperUser, and then delete my account. Yes, like a revenge for the treatment that I've received from stackexchange staff members.

I don't want to still be a part of this site, that's what matters for me.

What I should do to delete all the answers where I helped people? and all the questions that I asked? and then my account?.

I sent a message to the support, waiting for a response.

PS: **I'm not going to change my decision**, I want to delete my account and everything I've contributed here, 
This is an angry decission, but I thought about it and is what I want, everyone has a limit and that moderator reached my limit, all that happened in superuser these days reached my limits of comprehension, starting by the reputation problems caused by the WRONG current privilege design.

A user can't add a comment on the answers that he receives on his OWN BOUNTY, and the same user can't give the bounty reward after his account is suspended (great for that helper user who can't receive my reward... ridiculously), All this is ridiculous and I've tried to explain it in superuser meta, but also I need to fight and be ridiculed by that moderator who suspended my account?, This is the end for my account.

Comment: No matter If I receive good or bad critics from moderators about this "question" because I know how much I'm raged, say me what you want, In this moments I can't find better and relaxed words to express myself, and the only thing that I want is someone who can explain me what I should do to delete all those things, to delete me and all what is related about me (MY ANSWERS) in this site.

Comment: Just a small thing, Stack Exchange is **not** a forum.

Comment: It is unbelievable what powers they gave the moderators. I got targeted after I left another site which a moderator runs in parallel. Everywhere else this would be a clear conflict of interest, but here they can get away with that.

Comment: As for any users your answers did or could help in the future, they aren't at fault, so I don't see why you'd want to

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can't. When you posted the content, you gave Stack Exchange an irrevocable license to use the content. You are welcome to delete your account if you wish to do so, which will remove your name from all the content you've previously posted.

See [How can I delete my account?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5999/how-can-i-delete-my-account)

Comment: Thanks for answer. to clarify: That's the only thing that will be removed if I remove my account?... the name?.

Comment: Ok so I see that stackExchange they act like bankers with him little words in contracts, while an user (AND HIM FRIEND) suffers the injustice of a moderator I can't do nothing more than delete my....name.

Comment: That "clausure" is just a clausure or is a LEGAL thing linked to U.S.A. justice? I mean, If they decide to keep all my answers/questions and I want the opposite thing (delete all), an advocate can do something about it? can win? or not because maybe the clausure is in better terms a legal thing for a judge?. I dont have intention to denounce that clausure (at least by the moment), anyways I just want to know all the possible information if in the future I get more unexpected problems by anybody of the staff members of stackexchange.

Comment: An advocate would probably just tell you there's nothing they can do because you agreed to the policy. In general, there is nothing you can do to get that content removed.

Comment: I see... nothing to do... its ok, thanks for your help, really!